# C++ and Sfml inheritance doesn't work

Tags: c++, inheritance, sfml

I have an inheritance problem.

```
class z
{
public:
    sf::RectangleShape rect1;
    int a ;

    z()
    {
       rect1.setFillColor(sf::Color::Red);
       rect1.setSize(sf::Vector2f(100,100));
        a = 5;
    }

    void movement()
    {
        if(sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Right))
        {

            rect1.move(1, 0);
            a = 6;

        }
    }  
};

class c : public z
{
public:
    void write()
    {
        std::cout << a;
    }
};

int main(int, char const**)
{
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(800, 600), "SFML window");

    z zclass;
    c cclass;

    while (window.isOpen())
    {

        zclass.movement();
        cclass.write();
        window.clear();
        window.draw(zclass.rect1);
        window.display();
    }

}
```

When I press right key, "a" variable always same result = "5". It should be "6". What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

`cclass` is a separate object and is independent from `zclass`, so they have separate member variables.

Try deleting `z zclass;` and changing `zclass.movement();` to `cclass.movement();`.

Comment: Its work but on releasing the right key value again going 5

Comment: @caatayk Do you mean that the value of `a` should become `5` when the key is released? Modify your code to do your desired behavior.

Answer (score 0):

it's actually quite natural let's explore why:

```
z zclass;   //that's an instance of the z class

c cclass;   //that's an instance of the c class
```

they're both independent means if you imagine your memory it has both,
both have their own "a" as members
so indeed you "told" z to move:

```
 zclass.movement();
```

but cclass never moved since a is a public member of both you can check

```
 std::cout << "zclass's a: " << zclass.a <<"\ncclasss's a: " << cclass.a;
```

will yields: 
zclass's a: 6
cclass's a: 5

notice that you want to make cclass move: means you need to write

cclass.movement();
now we've said to the z part in cclass "heya budd move ur ass so a=6"

one more thing more about coding. not everything should have public access think of it like that:
public -everyone can access maybe a is some core thing in your game like the character gold or xp do you really want someone else to change it?

private - only the current class can do stuff with it, we don't even let the classes that inherit from us access to this important data.

protected- both me and people who inherit from me can use this data

classes inheritance means that c contains a part of z object like c has it's own part and part of it it's z

now when you do something like 
z z1,z2; they're completely different like when you do 
int a,b they're different 
if u do a=3; b is not 3

i suggest take some books on c++ topic and work with them prior on taking libraries like sfml :)

good luck!